# Perforce trigger won't run rubyscript

Tags: perforce

`jenkins change-submit //... "ruby %quote%//HVS/Main/BuildScripts/notify_jenkins.rb%quote%"`

So I have made the above p4 trigger in my triggers file, and I'm trying to run a build script file that I wrote in ruby but when I try to submit a file, I'm getting this error:

```
'jenkins' validation failed: ruby: No such file or directory -- //HVS/Main/BuildScripts/notify_jenkins.rb (LoadError)
```

Is there no way to make a p4 trigger run a file that's inside of a stream? The documentation says you can do this, but when I try to run it, it's saying it can't find the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the doc:

https://www.perforce.com/perforce/r14.2/manuals/p4sag/chapter.scripting.html#basics.scripts.depot

the format you want is:

```
jenkins change-submit //... "ruby %//HVS/Main/BuildScripts/notify_jenkins.rb%"
```

Surrounding it in `%quote%` characters means you're expecting the OS to be able to interpret that path as a local filesystem path.